# dgrid - how to download samples and find doc

Tags: dojo, dgrid

This page shows a sample I want to reproduce: 
http://dgrid.io/js/dgrid/test/Tree.html
(or any other of the samples here: http://dgrid.io/js/dgrid/test/)

I did a "view source" to see the code, but poking around and so far haven't found the data file "dgrid/test/data/hierarchicalCountryData".

It doesn't seem to be included in the code samples from GitHub (dgrid@1.2.1).

Also the normal doc/samples on the website don't show much about these tree features.  I think I found it by doing a site:dgrid.io tree.  So is this future research, or something currently available?

Comment: Okay, got the data: view-source:http://dgrid.io/js/dgrid/test/data/hierarchicalCountryData.js.  Was used to the other example where it was a .json file, but then it dawned on me that if it's a require, it is obviously a .js extension.

Comment: One by one, I've found and downloaded about 7 files required, now I can try it out.  But still curious if this is current and supported and why not included in the main install/demos.

Comment: They are part of the official source distribution at the following link: https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/releases/tag/v1.2.1

Comment: Thanks. I see it there.  I think I stalled dgrid via npm of NodeJS.  Is the package.json the best way to find out what version you have installed? The bower files are same, but the package.json's are very different.  If you want to put that comment as answer I will vote it as answer.  Maybe with npm you have to ask for the tests to be downloaded with some parm?

Comment: No worry for the vote :-). As per npm, I am not familiar enough with it answer your question